# Ubuntu USB Boot Question

Tags: boot, usb, chromebook

I have an old HP Chromebook 14 (Falco) that I removed the SSD from to replace the damaged one in another Chromebook of the same model. I'm wondering if I can use this old Chromebook (which doesn't have an SSD) as a Linux Laptop that boots Ubuntu from a USB.

I doubt it's actually possible because the lack of the SSD would prevent me from using SeaBIOS and launching any USB image, but I was wondering if anyone here might have any thoughts that could work. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to boot with Ubuntu bootable USB? or atleast without the SSD are you able to see BIOS screen?

Comment: Yup. I’m obviously in developer mode so the first thing that appears is the OS Verification screen. From there, Ctrl+L (shortcut to get to SeaBIOS) just makes beeping sounds as if SeaBIOS hasn’t been installed, and Ctrl+U (shortcut to boot from external media when “enable_dev_usb_boot” is enabled) just shows a message saying that booting from an external drive has not been configured. I’ll have to copy the exact error message later today because I’m away from my laptop right now and am  just describing this all from memory.

Comment: seems the wording "shortcut to boot from external media when "enable_dev_usb_boot" is enabled" `booting from an external drive has not been configured` this seems somewhat positive.. but I understand you are not with the laptop now.. when you are with laptop and live usb.. lets chat.. https://www.coreboot.org/SeaBIOS#Linux

Comment: see the USB and Legacy boot options.. https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/acer-c720-chromebook